# Diazo: css:if-content and css:if-not-content are both matched

Tags: plone, diazo

I am using Diazo in a Plone (4.2) site, and in the rules.xml file I have something like this (this is simplified, but I tested this simplified version too).:

```
    <rules css:if-not-content=".add-post-link">
        <replace css:content="#content" css:theme="#document-content" />
    </rules>

    <rules css:if-content=".add-post-link">
        <drop css:content=".documentFirstHeading" />
    </rules>
```

The problem is that both the "replace" and the "drop" directives are being applied, which means that both conditions "css:if-content" and "css:if-not-content" are being met, even though they are complementary, i.e, one and only one of them should be true at a time. (By the way, if I switch the order of the two "rules" directives the result is the same)

Does anyone understand this behaviour? Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it. Please reduce it to a minimal failing example (preferably one that can be run from the command line using diazorun) and post it to the bug tracker at https://dev.plone.org/ with the diazo tag and I'll try and take a look.